# Wait for 2 minutes before executing the select statement in SQL Server - WAIT FOR DELAY

Tags: sql-server

After inserting the record, I have to wait for 2 minutes before getting the last insert record number.
I am not sure how reliable is to use WAIT FOR DELAY clause.

What is the impact if thousands are people using the functionality at the same time and try to create a record from front end?
Can it lock the table?

Can somebody let me know what is the best way to do it.

Comment: Why do you have to wait for 2 minutes in the first place?

Comment: "After inserting the record, I have to wait for 2 minutes before getting the last insert record number." ..wtf? Best way is to fix the two minute delay.

Comment: There is another process which runs continuously and change the status of last inserted record and takes around 90-120 seconds to do this. Since I only want to capture the updated record, I would have to wait for 120 seconds.

Comment: Wait in the client then and issue a second query. You SHOULD get the last inserted ID right after the insert anyways.

Comment: This will depend on:

The context in which you run the WAITFOR DELAY. From the documentation; "Blocks the execution of a batch, stored procedure, or transaction until a specified time or time interval is reached, or a specified statement modifies or returns at least one row."
The method in which you get "last insert record number"; IDENT_CURRENT( 'table_name' ), SCOPE_IDENTITY(), or @@IDENTITY. As far as your "other process", that's the process that should get the inserted id, otherwise you'll always be guessing at when it's done.

Comment: everything needs to be done within same stored proc due to some limitations.

Comment: And yet, it isn't. From your comment: "There is another process which runs continuously and change the status of last inserted record and takes around 90-120 seconds to do this. Since I only want to capture the updated record, I would have to wait for 120 seconds. – user3057913 10 mins ago"

Comment: Other process is window's service hosted on third party side.

Comment: Can you pick up the record by uniqueness rather than inserted ID? Regardless, you're always going to be at the mercy of the timing on the windows process as it can update after you get the record, but picking up the record by uniqueness based on MAX(ID) or MAX([inserted_date]) might be more reliable.

Comment: Yes, I can pick up the last inserted record but the issue is that it needs to be picked up only if the window's service has changed the status of last inserted record.

Comment: No idea why you would want to do this: but it would be `WAITFOR DELAY '00:02'` Can't you just fix the delay? What if it finishes after two minutes?

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  Using a time based trigger to continue a workflow will cause you many problems.  Find some way to identify the updated record and when it was updated so you are not bound to some arbitrary time value.

Comment: If it goes more than 2 minutes then it should kill the process the exit form SP with an error code.

Comment: This is a bad idea for one connection. Let alone thousands. "Each WAITFOR statement has a thread associated with it. If many WAITFOR statements are specified on the same server, many threads can be tied up waiting for these statements to run. SQL Server monitors the number of threads associated with WAITFOR statements, and randomly selects some of these threads to exit if the server starts to experience thread starvation." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

It may be an option to query the id immediatly after the insert. Store that in a variable, wait for 2 minutes and then again query for updated results, using your variable in the where clause.